# Update json value if attempt is made to same key name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to write a function which updates a json key value if an attempt is made to add a new key with same name

So in fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/adrianjsfiddlenetuser/C6Ssa/57/

When the button "Add" is clicked the jSon array toUpdate should be updated :

```
   name: "addThis2",
   id : 10
```

should become

```
   name: "addThis2",
   id : 11
```

This is not occuring ?

Sample JSON :

```
{
    "toAdd": [
        {
            "name": "addThis",
            "id": 10
        }
    ],
    "toRemove": [
        {
            "name": "removeThis"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: JSON doesn't support duplicate key?

Comment: @thecodeparadox I dont know what you mean, ive updated my question with sample JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the index of array like folowing:

```
var toUpdate = {
    toAdd: [],
    toRemove: []
};
toUpdate.toAdd[0].push({
    name: "addThis1",
    id: 10
});
toUpdate.toRemove[0].push({
    name: "removeThis1"
});
toUpdate.toAdd[1].push({
    name: "addThis2",
    id: 10
});
toUpdate.toRemove[1].push({
    name: "removeThis2"
});
```

Then you can try

```
$.each(toUpdate, function(index, data) {
   $.each(data, function(key, val) {  // here this refer to toAdd, toRemove..
    console.log(key);   // here this point key of object like name, id ...
    console.log(val[key]);  // output: addThis, addThis, removeThis
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function updateKeyVal() {
    $.each(toUpdate, function(i,e) {
        $.each(e, function(j, f) {
            if (f.name===valToCheck) f.id=11;
        });
    });
}​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/C6Ssa/60/)